How to resolve the error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile" when building docker file?
I try to dockerize a next.js app.
So I have this Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine AS BUILD_IMAGE
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .

RUN yarn build

RUN npm prune --production
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/public ./public
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]


But when I try to build the Dockerifile with the command:
docker build -t frontend:v1 -f Dockerfile.prod .

I get this error:
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

on this line:
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

Question: how to resolve the error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile"

The "exit code 1" error just means "it didn't work".  There should be some error output from yarn above that; can you [edit] the question to include the complete error message, and possibly an extract of the package.json file if that's relevant?  The first couple of lines of the Dockerfile seem fine.

@DavidMaze. Thank you for your contribution. I added some feedback.

I had to do with yarn install. I couldn't install the node_modules. So I deleted  the lock file. But then again I got some errors. So I deleted the node_modules. And then I got some errors about installing
"@mui/utils": "^5.15.20",

So I installed that package. I dit again a yarn install. And then it wokred - I could build the docker image without errors.
